# Graylog on/off state line chart

Tags: graylog

I have a process the report on/off state to the graylog.
Is there a way to chart it?

Process sends message when it starts/stops. I can mend value(s) it send.
Chart would show let say line=1 on start till the next stop,
Then zero on stop until next start, aka step.
I can manage just spikes at message arrival, but not line between events.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

You would need to translate the on/off values of your field to numeric values. The best way to do this is to use a pipeline for the messages, that checks if the field value equals "on" or "off" and writes a 1 or 0 to a new numeric field. You can chart this field then.

You can find more information about pipelines here: http://docs.graylog.org/en/2.4/pages/pipelines/pipelines.html

Comment: I read the documentation, but I could not figure out, pipeline allows to modify the messages, I need to modify the chart how it represent. The number is not problem. Let says I want to display bars of active threads in my application. This is number already. So when I create 10 threads i sent msg t=10. Then 1 hour later I add 4 threads and sent t=14, On a chart it would be just 2 events, and if I apply pipeline it still would be 2 events. How I get a horizontal bar 10 until it changes to 14...